# Laravel/Ajax/SQL: trying to show the current value on when null or not

Tags: sql, ajax, laravel, function, edit

Below is a screenshot of my table. My goal is in the `effective_start_datetime`, I want it to show as status `active` if there is a value in it, and `inactive` if it is `null` when editing. (show current status on edit click)

[image: 2]

**Model:** (getting the SQL data)

```
$group_edit = HmsBbrGroup::find($group_id);
```

**Table:**

```
<select id="edit_effective_start_datetime" class="form-control w-100 edit_effective_start_datetime">
<option value="active">Active</option>
<option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
</select>
```

**Form:** (only status is not showing)

[image: 2]

**Ajax:** (output form content when the edit button is clicked)

```
        $(document).on('click','.edit_group',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var g_id = $(this).val();
            console.log(g_id);
            $('#editGroupModal').modal('show');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/clinical/bbr-group-configuration-edit/"+g_id,
                success: function (response) {
                     console.log(response);
                    if(response.status == 404) {
                        $('#success_message').html("");
                        $('#success_message').addClass('alert alert-danger');
                        $('#success_message').text('response.message');
                    } else {
                        $('#edit_group_name').val(response.group_edit.group_name);
                        $('#edit_group_description').val(response.group_edit.group_description);
                        $('#edit_group_id').val(response.group_edit.group_id);

                        $('#edit_effective_start_datetime').val(response.group_edit.effective_start_datetime).change();
                        $('#edit_group_type_id').val(response.group_edit.group_type_id).change();
                    }
                    
                }
            });
        });
```

As you can see from the form, my ajax outputs the contents besides the status here in `$('#edit_effective_start_datetime').val(response.group_edit.effective_start_datetime).change();` I am trying to figure out the solution to show the `<option>` as `inactive` or `active` if the `datetime` is `null` or not

I tried to add a function but this is not working:

```
                    $('#edit_effective_start_datetime').val(getgroupstatus(response.group_edit.edit_effective_start_datetime)).change();

function getgroupstatus(status) {
  var g_status = '';
  if (status === null) {
    g_status = 'inactive'
  } else {
    g_status = 'active'
  } 
  return g_status;
}
```

Any help/advice on how to show the status would help alot, thanks.

Comment: The value for the options are `active` and `inactive`  so in assign try `.val(response.group_edit.effective_start_datetime ? 'active' : 'inactive')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use boolean values instead of strings - and your code will be simpler

```
<select id="edit_effective_start_datetime">
    <option value=0>Inactive</option>
    <option value=1>Active</option>
<select>

$("#edit_effective_start_datetime").val(response.group_edit.effective_start_datetime === null ? 0 : 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use prop

```
    var effective_start_datetime=response.group_edit.edit_effective_start_datetime?
                                'active':
                                'inactive';

    $('#edit_effective_start_datetime option[value='+effective_start_datetime+']').prop("selected",true);
```